# Running a php script asynchronously

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a web page with a button, when a user taps the button there is a long php script that runs (say to look at past tokens bought by the user) and sends the user an email at the end of script.

I have abstracted my code for sharing purpose (replacing the script with just a sleep function).

**webpage.php**

```
<div class="card">
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="update" value="Update" />
</div>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="jquery_functions.js"></script>
```

**jquery_functions.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input[name="update"]').click(function() {
        $.post(
                "script.php",
                {update:"fav_tokens"},
                function($data) {
                    alert ($data.message);
                },
                "json"
            );
    });

});
```

**script.php**

```
<?php
    sleep(60);
?>
```

The problem is that as soon as the user presses on the button, he is "locked in" on the page and cannot navigate away from it... which kind of defeats the purpose of doing the jQuery AJAX thing.

I have tried putting the script in another file (**script2.php**) and then call it using `exec("php -f script2.php");` in script.php but that also stop the user from navigating away from the page.

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: make input type as button or make form prevent default using form tag and JS function. Just make your input type button from type submit.

Comment: Can you explain "he is "locked in" on the page and cannot navigate away from it"?  Do you mean that the PHP server becomes unresponsive to other requests?

Comment: You can use [Symphone event dispacher](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher.html) package from composer. let the task run in the background and get back to the user immediately with a nice message like "we are processing your request"..

Comment: @D.Walsh - not to requests from other users, but for this user - links that navigate away from the page stop working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likely issue is that `script.php` is opening a session and whichever page you are trying to visit is also trying to open a session but has to wait until `script.php` is all set with it.

Somewhere in `script.php` you will need to add:

```
ignore_user_abort(1); // Let the script run even if user leaves the page
set_time_limit(0);    // Let script run forever

session_write_close(); // Close the session. This will allow for other pages to open it
                       // You will still be able to read your session data but can no longer write to it unless it is re-opened

sleep(60);
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks @MonkeyZeus